# customized behaviour for jtabbedpane tabs

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am building GUI for file browser which will display files & folders inside directory.
[File Explorer with TopBar(JPanel) on top, TabPane(JTabbedPane) on lower right, and LeftPanel(JPanel) on lower left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1aei.png)

[image]

'+' button on top adds new tabs to jtabbedpane, '<' button on top bring back to the parent folder, and leftPanel is for shortcuts. I am using JList to display files and folders. this jlist is added to JScrollPane and then to JTabbedpane.

Problem now comes when i add new tabs and then switch to other tabs but the changes made by '<' button and leftPanel only execute on the last tab. I need to find a solution by which i can tell '<' Back button to make change only on the selected tab. how can i achieve this?
i am sharing code of some classes. FilesInTheJList.java is the class which is used to display files inside jtabbedpane.

LeftPanel.java

```
public class LeftPanel extends JPanel
{

public  JList<Object> leftList;
public static DefaultListModel<Object> listModel;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public LeftPanel(TabPane tabbedPane){
    leftList = new JList<Object>();
    String leftNamesString[] = {"Downloads","Desktop", "Documents", "Pictures", "Movies", "Users", "Sharing"};
    listModel = new DefaultListModel<Object>();
    for (String list: leftNamesString) {
        listModel.addElement(list);
    }
    leftList.setModel(listModel);
    leftList.setFixedCellHeight(30);
    leftList.setFixedCellWidth(150);
    leftList.setFont(new Font("SansSerif",Font.PLAIN,16));
    leftList.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(10, 5, 5, 0, Color.WHITE));
    leftList.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    leftList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
    addAction(tabbedPane);
    listRoots();
}
public void listRoots() {
    File[] paths;
    paths = File.listRoots();
    for(File path:paths)
    {
        listModel.addElement(path.toString());
    }
    leftList.invalidate();
    leftList.repaint();

}
public void addAction(TabPane tabbedPane){
    leftList.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
            switch(leftList.getSelectedValue().toString()){
            case "Downloads":
                    tabbedPane.showFilesInTheJList.repaintList(home+"/Downloads/");
                break;
            case "Desktop":
                    tabbedPane.showFilesInTheJList.repaintList(home+"/Desktop/");

                break;
            case "Documents":
                tabbedPane.showFilesInTheJList.repaintList(home+"/Documents/");

                break;
            case "Pictures":
                    tabbedPane.showFilesInTheJList.repaintList(home+"/Pictures/");
                break;
            case "Movies":
                    tabbedPane.showFilesInTheJList.repaintList(home+"/Movies/");

                break;
            case "Users":
                    tabbedPane.showFilesInTheJList.repaintList("/Users/");

                break;
            case "Sharing":
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                SharingGui openSharingGui = new SharingGui();
                break;
            default:
                tabbedPane.showFilesInTheJList.repaintList(leftList.getSelectedValue().toString());
                break;
            }
        }
        //other empty mouse pressed/released methods
    });
}
private static class MyCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Object> {

    //not so important stuff
}
}
```

tabpane.java

```
public class TabPane extends JTabbedPane{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String pathString;
public FilesInTheJList showFilesInTheJList;

TabPane()
{
    setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    pathString = "/Users/jaspreet/Downloads/";
}
public void addTabs() 
{
    if (getTabCount() == 0) {
        showFilesInTheJList = new FilesInTheJList();
        showFilesInTheJList.paintList(pathString);
        addTab(showFilesInTheJList.parentDirName, new JScrollPane(showFilesInTheJList.list));
    }
    else {
        showFilesInTheJList = new FilesInTheJList();
        showFilesInTheJList.paintList(pathString);
        insertTab(showFilesInTheJList.parentDirName, null,new JScrollPane(showFilesInTheJList.list), showFilesInTheJList.parentDirName, getTabCount());
        initTabComponent(getTabCount()-1);
    }
}
private void initTabComponent(int i) {
    this.setTabComponentAt(i, new ButtonTabComponent(this));
}
}
```

both of them are called from splitpane.java

splitpane.java

```
public class SplitPane extends JPanel
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public JSplitPane splitPane;
public TabPane tabbedPane;

SplitPane(){
    tabbedPane = new TabPane();
    tabbedPane.addTabs();

    LeftPanel leftSplit = new LeftPanel(tabbedPane);
    splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,new JScrollPane(leftSplit.leftList), tabbedPane);
    splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
    splitPane.setContinuousLayout(true);
}
}
```

Comment: You need to ascertain the currently selected "tab", find it's "component" and pass functionality to it.  One possible solution would be to maintain a `Map` of each tab and it's associated "view", so based on the currently selected tab, you could get the tabs "name" and use it to look up the associated view and then call the required functionality for that view.  Have a look at [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

Comment: i have no idea how to work with `Map` . any tutorials or any other way around.? i can share the project with you in private to have more information about it.

Comment: [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: thankyou @MadProgrammer for looking into this problem, but i was able to achieve it with some dirty workaround by using `getComponentAt` method